# How to properly display data in chartjs from SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I got started with chartJS, so I really need guidance of where to look and learn. I'm trying to display duplicated data from my SQL to chartJS.

Example: 
**Table name:** Traffic Violations 
**Data I want to display:** Violation types (Speeding, drifting, seatbelt, etc). 
**How it should be displayed:** Y-axis as numbers, X-axis as violation names.

I read this: [SQL count how many duplicated values of a derived table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054597/sql-count-how-many-duplicated-values-of-a-derived-table) 
Watched this: [1.3: Graphing with Chart.js - Working With Data & APIs in JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-ptp9tRApM) 
also watched this: [How to Switch Chart to Daily, Weekly and Monthly Data in Chart js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVHi41f7psQ) 
And this: [Count Total number of rows in database in php -Analytics in php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LCeU20v-QQ)

I learned few things from each, but still didn't satisfy my knowledge needs to achieve the goal I want.

I want to display the data in "Daily", "Monthly", "Yearly" format.

Sounds like that's a totally different topic, because I want the "daily" chart to reset every 24 hours, and monthly every month without deleting the data from DB. None of these videos above shows me that, nor I couldn't find what I'm looking for..

So, how to prepare my DB for chartJS? 
best practice to fetch data and show it in the chart?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once('./backend/config/connection.php');

$sqlQuery = "SELECT violationType, count(*) AS duplicates FROM traffic_violations GROUP BY violationType ORDER BY duplicates DESC";

$statement = $connection->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

if ($row->num_rows > 0) 
{
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $row->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
    echo $row["duplicates"]. "<br>";
  }
} 
else 
{
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**Chart:**

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart-test').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ['Speeding', 'Drifting', 'Sealtbelt', 'Wrong Parking', 'Wrong Lane Drive', 'No License'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Traffic Violations',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132)'],
          borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132)'],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    });
```